# Max programs in GLSL ES

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

What is the maximum number of programs that can be compiled in GLSL ES?
So lets say I create 100 fragment shaders, each is a different effect. So at runtime I compile all of them and dynamically I swap them with glUseProgram.
I assume that everytime I compile a new GLSL-ES program it holds in somwhere in the GPU. Is there any maximum number of the amount of active compiled programs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no maximum limit. Only limitation is available memory or other resources that is controlled by GPU or its driver.

In a same way there is no maximum limit for count of texture objects or vertex buffer objects.